# Fetching React native contacts and sending it to backend to fetch existing user in app

Tags: react-native, react-native-contacts

- *Here i am fetching all contacts from user's device and formatting it all to pass in API. and some numbers are with country code and some
  are without country code. so here i also formatting all the contacts
  without country code. this process runs like 2-3 minutes and my final
  was like this*  Please suggest if i am doing this in wrong way. or
  any improvement will be appreciated. OR what's the best way to do this kind of time taking things silently without freezing the app. THANKS IN ADVANCE

  ```
   const contacts = [{fullname: "Mark", mobileNumber: "1234567890", cc: "+1"}, {...}, {...}]
  ```

And i pass this array straight to backend. here's my full code how i am getting and formatting it.

```
   const phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
  ContactServices.askForContactPermission((resolve) => {
    BusyIndicator.show()
    console.log("permission", resolve);
    getContacts().then((res) => {
      res.map((c) => {
        if (c?.phoneNumbers[0]?.number) {
          if (c?.phoneNumbers[0]?.number.includes("+")) {
            const phone_parse = phoneNumberUtil.parse(c?.phoneNumbers[0]?.number);
            const country_code = c?.phoneNumbers[0]?.number.includes("+") ? "+" + phone_parse.getCountryCode(c?.phoneNumbers[0]?.number) : ""
            const mobile = phone_parse.getNationalNumber(phone_parse);
            setContacts(prevState => [...prevState, { fullname: c?.givenName, mobileNumber: mobile.toString().replace(/\s/g, ''), cc: country_code }])
          } else {
            setContacts(prevState => [...prevState, { fullname: c?.givenName, mobileNumber: c?.phoneNumbers[0]?.number.toString().replace(/\s/g, ''), cc: "" }])
          }
        }
      })
getFriendsByContact() // my backend api call when i got all the contacts.
    }).catch((error) => {
      BusyIndicator.hide()
      console.log("error", error);
    })
  }, (reject) => {
    BusyIndicator.hide()
    console.log("permission", reject);
  })
```

Comment: So, how much is this "some time" that is spent with react-native-contacts? And how much goes to everything else?

Comment: Around 10 minutes. Sometime backend api also fails working with 1000-1500 contacts

Comment: So instead of taking 5-8 minutes, it takes 15-18 minutes in total?

Comment: More than 15-18 minutes and everytime api fails to fetch and load all data

Comment: So, most of the time is spent in logic that's written by you, which you have not shared with us -- and we should tell how to improve it?